# Is javascript "use strong" feature accepted as a web standard?

Tags: javascript, html, web, v8

Google started to experiment with "use strong" as a stricter alternative than javascript "use strict".

I have not heard anything from it since they published this blog post:

https://developers.google.com/v8/experiments

Does anybody know if this is finally a standard and can be used with javascript projects?

Comment: Have you looked at this document?  [Strong Mode Proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qk0qC4s_XNCLemj42FqfsRLp49nDQMZ1y7fwf5YjaI4/view)

Comment: Thanks, it is interesting, but still no info about the proposal status

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a standard, and (unfortunately) unlikely to become one soon. Here's the last official update: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/strengthen-js/ojj3TDxbHpQ

TL;DR:

> ...we have reluctantly decided not to pursue strong mode further. We learned some worthwhile lessons, but overall it is not clear that the benefits justify the costs. Starting with the next version of V8, we will hence remove support for strong mode.

Comment: I typed too slow, looks like we've answered with the same content. If you put the relevant information from the link in your answer I'll delete mine and upvote yours since you got there first. It's best to not have the bulk of an answer be a link as links are prone to change.